# Can not configure proxy_pass in nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I want to pass a request to an HTTP proxied server, the proxy_pass directive is specified inside a location.

And in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` I configure :

```
server { location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
}
}
```

And when I execute this command  `service nginx start`:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of `systemctl status nginx.service`

```
 ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-11-02 20:25:51 UTC; 53s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 12219 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9516 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11760 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 27870 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11763 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 02 20:25:51 ubuntu-s-milos2611 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 02 20:25:51 ubuntu-s-milos2611 nginx[27870]: nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:72
Nov 02 20:25:51 ubuntu-s-milos2611 nginx[27870]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Nov 02 20:25:51 ubuntu-s-milos2611 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 02 20:25:51 ubuntu-s-milos2611 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 20:25:51 ubuntu-s-milos2611 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: Did you run `systemctl status nginx.service` as suggested in the output? It will provide you with more details about the issue.

Comment: Now you can see the status.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the http:// prefix in your proxy_pass directive:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```

Check http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks, now I do not have an error.  And my Nginx is started. 
But I still do not have a connection betwine my UI on port 80 and backend who is started with Tomcat on port 8080. Do you have any proposal for that?

Answer (score 0):

Change your config file to

```
server { 
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
```

You are adding `location ~^/api/(.*)$` twice which is not correct.